# Find AIDL's stub implementation code in Android using Eclipse/AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I often see many Android source codes using `AIDL` and for example `interface` of `IStatusBarService` below is defined by `IStatusBarService.aidl`.

```
    IStatusBarService mStatusBarService = IStatusBarService.Stub.asInterface(
                    ServiceManager.getService("statusbar"));
    if (mStatusBarService != null) {
        mStatusBarService.expandNotificationsPanel();
    }
```

However, how could I find  implementation source code of IStatusBarService's stub using Eclipse/Android Studio? Which short cut key?

For example: where is `implementation` code of `expandNotificationsPanel()` function?

[Remark]
With normal function, in `Eclipse` we could point to that function and press F3 or [RightMouse/Open Declaration] to see `implementation` code. 
But with `AIDL` function, it will not go to `implementation` code but auto generated `AIDL` code which is not our expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Is this what you need?In my mind, there is no shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest but it is not what I mentioned. 
Your method is used when you know exactly the path where the source code file is.
But what I expect is when you don't remember and you want to navigate the source as fast as possible you often use shortcut key such as Ctrl+Shift+T (find class), Ctrl+O (find method & member variable in a class), F3 (find declaration). It increases productivity.